# Function not returning value in while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, return

I've written a function which is supposed to find the point of intersection between two functions and return the values as a list xn until the error is less than the desired tolerance, but it's not returning any values at all for me - not getting an error message either.

I'm a complete newbie to python so I'm sure it's something very basic in the syntax, but I've been messing around with the code for a while and can't seem to get anything out of it.

```
def fixpoint(x0,tol):
    x=x0
    xn=[x]
    error=1+tol
    while error > tol:
        xm = x0
        x = 1/(np.sqrt(1+np.exp(2*x0*x0)))
        error = abs(x-xm)
        xn.append(x)
    return xn

fixpoint(0.6,1e-15)
```

Comment: Yes the function is returning a value. How are you running this code? Note that you're not *printing* the result.

Comment: You need to debug your code. Put in lots of print statements to discover what is happening. Your tolerance is also a tiny value.

Comment: Your tolerance is too small. Your code results in an infinite loop because `error` gets stuck with the value `0.0278173517728`.

Comment: if it wasnt so small all you'd need to do at the end is `print(fixpoint(0.6,1e-15))` which will print `xn` when it gets to it

Comment: @Aran-Fey I don't seem to get a value either with a bigger tolerance though.

Comment: What are you doing with the returned value?

Comment: result = fixpoint(0.6,1e-15)
print result
# OR
do_something_with(result)

Comment: @Aditya I'm just trying to print it, tried what you suggested and still get no value - even with a smaller tolerance as suggested by some others.